# Run Visual Studio 2016

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have all these packages because I have had in my PC a previous version from Visual Studio. But I have to install Visual Studio 2016. My question is: will it have any problem trying to run in the future although I have these things?.
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2016, only 2015 and 2017

Comment: Short Answer **no**. The newer versions of Visual Studio will see you already have those dependencies and would most likely not install them. Also some other programs on your computer might be using them.

Comment: By the way, your screenshot only shows redistributables which are required to *run* programs compiled with Visual Studio, you'll have them installed even if you never had installed Visual Studio itself

Comment: What should I do in this situation? Because I installed visual studio professional and what I what to install is visual enterprise. I had some problems trying to install professional 2012 so I've deleted the package that it installed

Comment: Just install whatever Visual Studio version you need? You seem so worried about *possible* problems that you don't even try to see what will happen

Comment: But what happens if I want to run a project I created with visual studio in my PC?

Comment: @F.Riggio All the newer IDE's still allow you to run your projects depending on older toolchains. Just configure them accordingly.

Comment: The situation is that I don't know the exact version that I need from Visual Studio but the most probable is that one. Maybe in some days I'll ask if the version that my boss confirms me that I have to use does not work. Thanks!

Comment: If you are unsure, just ask your boss politely which version they recommend.